# How we can bind an enumeration exists in a class in another module (pybind11)

Tags: python, c++, enums, binding, pybind11

I want to use the enumeration OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE of the class_1 in another class_2.
the global idea is to bind the class_2 using pybind11 in order to use it in python.

```
class class_1
{
public:

    typedef enum
    {
        enum_value_1,
        enum_value_2,       
        enum_value_3,           
        enum_value_4                

    }OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE;
};

class class_2{
public: 
      class_2();
      class_2(const class_1::OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE nt);

};

void export_class_2(py::module &m)
{

    py::enum_<class_1::OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE>(m, "OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE")
        .value("enum_value_1", class_1::OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE::enum_value_1)
        .value("enum_value_2", class_1::OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE::enum_value_2)
        .value("enum_value_3", class_1::OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE::enum_value_3)
        .value("enum_value_4", class_1::OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE::enum_value_4)
        .export_values();
    .def(py::init<const class_1::OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE>(), py::arg("nt") = enum_value_1);

}
```

the compilation works well but when I try to test it in python

```
print(class_2.OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE.enum_value_1)
```

I have this error :

```
 print(class_2.OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE.enum_value_1)
AttributeError: type object 'class_2' has no attribute 'OBJECT_ENUM_TYPE'
```

Comment: Someone can help me please ?